# Can i know if a set of files in one folder are contained in another drive or folder?

Tags: windows

I have an old (a couple of years) backup folder of a lot of files someone asked me to keep for them. Of course, It has several subfolders with a lot of files within.

Recently, i made another backup for that person, but this new backup of course has much newer things, and some other things have been moved and or deleted. For example, music before was only thrown into several folders, without being organized by album/artist whatever, and now it has the same music, and new music, sorted in a different way.

The same occurs with pictures and some other files, that is, the old backup had a lot of files in just a few folders, and the new backup has the same (plus new) files, ordered in a different structure.

What i want to do, is somehow "compare" the old backup with the new one, to know if absolutely all of the "old" files, are contained in the "new" backup, knowing that they may not have the same file/folder structure.
That way, i could be sure that the whole "old" backup is safe to delete, because everything would be already in the new one (otherwise, i just need to copy the few files that are not already in the new backup, and then delete the old one)

Of course i know that if both versions had the same folder structure, i could do a very simple compare process, (e.g. with winmerge) and just query for the "left only" files , which would be the ones not contained in the new backup. but the problem is that the folders and files are now organized very differently.

In other words, is there a way of querying if all files in one folder (and its subfolders) are already somewhere in other folder/subfolders, but with a different "structure"?

The old and new backup folders are each in a different partition, and i am running windows 7 pro. If you need more details, please ask me.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a few duplicate file finders such as this one:

http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/duplicate-file-finder/

It is not dependent on having similar data structures.